# What is the best way to review Spanish quickly

Tags: gramática, vocabulario

Some years ago, I learned Spanish through about a high intermediate level.  I've used the language occasionally in intervening years, but overall I've become a little rusty.

For career purposes, it would be beneficial to polish my Spanish skills, but apart from doing random exercises, I'm not sure the best way to approach this.  I don't really have the time or means to be formally assessed.

What would be the best way to review the essentials in a short time to be able to use Spanish at about an intermediate level for practical purposes?

Thanks

Comment: Disagree that this is a duplicate.  There's a difference between learning the language and reviewing the essentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is intended to supplement the answer by J. Taylor.

If you can find an old-fashioned book that provides a succinct format, you could work your way through the whole book in about three months.  I used such a book, which I bought at a second-hand bookstore.  It was from the University of Chicago, and it was printed with thin paper during World War II.  Each chapter presented a grammar concept with an explanation in Spanish, and about 20 new vocabulary words were introduced, and illustrated in a short dialogue and a short narrative text.  The last thing in each chapter was a set of exercises.  My book didn't have recordings but if you can get a book with accompanying recordings that would be even better.  Good places to look are public libraries, second-hand bookstores, and "Friends of the Library" booksales.

It's helpful to study out loud.  Speak slowly by prolonging your vowels.  Look in a small mirror -- this will help you keep your vowels pure.

You can learn at least 20 vocabulary items per week if

(a) the items are connected somehow (such as in the textbook I described)

(b) you cover up the Spanish and try to produce the English and then vice versa; keep in mind that for something to be stored in your long term memory, it is helpful to put it in your short term memory about 7 times

(c) you find a mnemonic (memory aid) to help you with the vocabulary items you're having trouble memorizing; for example, I had trouble learning "sonrisa [smile]," and the mnemonic I came up with was to think of "sunrise," which I thought looked just enough like "sonrisa" to help me go from "smile" to "sunrise" to "sonrisa."

Somewhere around the midpoint you'll be ready to start composing your own sentences.  This is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

A few years back, I got a job where I worked with many Spanish-speaking people, and also started doing regular (weekly) childcare for a Spanish-speaking child. I was in the same situation where my Spanish was very rusty, and I felt unable to comfortably have basic conversations. The tools I have used to get myself back up to speed were:

- Using a Spanish [word frequency list](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Frequency_lists/Spanish1000) to refresh the vocabulary you're most likely to need -- that is, a list of the thousand or so words that are most frequently used in Spanish speech/writing. Study this list, make flashcards, and quiz yourself on them regularly. Another related tool that is useful to have is a book (or [list](https://www.spanishdict.com/guide/the-100-most-common-spanish-verbs)) of the most common Spanish verbs and their conjugations. I would generally try to pick at least three or four verbs a day, and practice with them in various tenses throughout the day. Also, make lists of vocabulary to study that are relevant to your everyday life (the things you do at work, the foods you like to eat, subjects you're interested in, etc).
- Using free online tools like [DuoLingo](https://www.duolingo.com/) to drill on basic grammar. Ideally do the lessons at different times throughout the day. Go to the library and get a college-level book on Spanish grammar. Try to work through a chapter a day.
- Find Spanish-language articles on a subject you're interested in, whether that is news, academic/science papers, sports, whatever. Watch Spanish-language films/television, and listen to Spanish music. The internet basically gives you an infinite supply of quality Spanish literature/media. Immerse yourself in it.
- I work a lot with computers, and one thing that I found helpful as a learning tool was to change my system's language settings to use Spanish as the default language. This made it where the user interface (menus, help pages, etc) were in Spanish, and made it so that many websites I visited defaulted to Spanish. It was frustrating at first and I sometimes had to "cheat" and switch the settings back to English to understand something, but it forced me to think in Spanish whenever I did anything at the computer (which meant several hours a day)
- Reach out in your local community and make Spanish-speaking friends, and regularly challenge yourself to speak Spanish (and make mistakes!) - having conversations in Spanish with native speakers is the single biggest thing that will improve your Spanish.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  At least the first three on the list are within my ability right now.  It's amazing how when you have been studying for a few days, things start to come back to you.  I've been reviewing verbs for about 4 or 5 days, and the conjugations are returning to memory.  The tricky part for me with reviewing a language is that there's so much to review that it's hard to know where to begin.

Comment: Yes, it definitely feels overwhelming trying to figure out where to start. That's why I highly encourage you to pick up a frequency list for vocabulary/verbs to focus on the most common 1000-2000 words. This narrows your focus down to what you're most likely to need in day-to-day conversation, basic reading and writing, etc. Start with the top 100 most common words (do the same with a list of verbs/conjugations), and work your way down the list ... Good luck, and congrats on choosing to pick up Spanish again!

Comment: Part of the problem of the returning language learner is that there's an awareness of how much one needs to practice and review.